# Ways to store JSON data

Tags: json, local-storage

I'm making an API call and the response I'm getting is a rather large JSON string. I'd like to minimise API calls to a) avoid hitting the rate limit and b) speed things up.

Here's an example of my JSON data:

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "isAlive": true,
  "age": 25,
  "address": {
    "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
    "city": "New York",
    "state": "NY",
    "postalCode": "10021-3100"
  },
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "type": "home",
      "number": "212 555-1234"
    },
    {
      "type": "office",
      "number": "646 555-4567"
    }
  ],
  "children": [],
  "spouse": null
}
```

**My question:**

What are my options with reference to persistent storage?

Please note: the API I'm using is in beta; so I'd like to avoid using MySQL for now because the JSON representation could change, resulting in my tables needing an overhaul.

Comment: When I do this, I usually just store it in memory in my application, but if you want to persist it, you could just use your favorite NoSQL database such as MongoDB?

Comment: I was thinking about MongoDB; but then there's things like Redis or storing it in a simple file. I'm trying to think of alternatives too.